# Оптимизация парсинга

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Добрый день. Есть главная страница сайта, на ней отображаются последние 10 новостей с сайта РЖД, дело в том, что сайт РЖД довольно медленный и из-за этого медленно загружается главная страница сайта, как это можно оптимизировать. Код парсинга

```
F3::set('news',   
    function() {
        include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
        $html = file_get_html('http://press.rzd.ru/news/public/press/');
        $i = "1";
        $title_ = array();
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($html->find('a[class=news_list_cardLink]') as $element) {
             $title_[$i] = $element->innertext; 
             echo "<li><a href='news/". $i ."'>'". $title_[$i] ."</a></li>";
             $i++;
             }
        echo "</ul>";
     }
);
```

Comment: Скидывать результаты парсинга в кэш, обновлять раз в пятнадцать минут по крону.

Answer (score 1):

А работать с RSS каналом не пробовали? Вот [тут](http://press.rzd.ru/rss/public/ru?STRUCTURE_ID=5220) ссылки на разные каналы.